# Unable to make a POST with ajax and JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, post

I am trying to make a POST with AJAX, but it doesn't recognize the parameters, it just does an empty POST...

Here is my ajax code :

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reserve-button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url : "generator/",
                data : {id: <?=$id?>},

                success : function(){
                    alert("Please give this code to your patient:" );
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("Erreur!!");
                }
            });

            return false;
    });
    });

    </script>
```

The HTML part :

```
<div class= "obutton feature2" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <button class="reserve-button">Reserve Book</button>
</div>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
{id: <?=$id?>}
```

isn't valid JS. First try with a hardcoded id, like

```
{ id: 1234 }
```

and if that works, then figure out why your templating code isn't correctly generating your id. : )

Comment: I did try that, it sends a post with no parameters at all